# What to do when browser back button doesn't have the intended effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I have a page where navigation is handled by hiding and showing preloaded divs when users click on links.  But, the users think they've actually changed pages, so they click on their browser's "back" button trying to go back to the div that was previously hidden.  But of course, they go back to the page from which they came.

What's the best way to handle this?  90% of the traffic is from a login page.  Should I just sandwich a redirect page in between the two?  How is this done?  Can I just change the browser's back button behavior?

Comment: You want the user to traverse back through the hidden divs they opened previously correct?

Comment: You can use named anchors (hash part in a url) trick which is quite popular practice these days. I am not totally sure how this is done but I hope someone will posts in the details soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery, why not simply add a [history manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin) like jq-bbq or the hashchange or history manager?  (Or, if you want to really go all out, switch to a MVC JavaScript framework like [Sammy](http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/index.html).)  That way, the back button will work as the user expects, rather than hacking around their expectations by blocking the back button or throwing in redirects.  (Unless you have a good reason to, of course :-) )

Comment: jq-bbq says it leverages the HTML5 hashchange event....does that mean poor IE support?

Comment: @Emile -- the author claims support for IE6 through 8, so I'd answer that tentatively as "no".

Answer (score 3):

If you use a browser history plugin like the jQuery UI one you end up changing the history so that the back button doesn't actually unload the page.

http://yoursite.com 
-> User clicks something
-> new address bar reads http://yoursite.com/#/something

because of the hash mark when user goes back it goes back to http://yoursite.com which should inturn fire your show previous div function

read more about the available history manager plugins available for jQuery.  There are quite a few.  Most if not all provide available callback functions that you can specify.

Answer (score 1):

On change of the state of your page, write a unique set of parameters to the hash of your URL. You can change this via JS without causing the page to reload.

Set a timer on the page that checks the current location hash repeatedly, and if it changes (i.e. the user presses the Back button) then update the state of your page to match the URL.

I have this scheme working to great effect in a local application.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Address library is another great alternative.
http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

You can set the URL for different application states, and get the URL 'parameters' when the page reloads.

Comment: thanks Osiris...I implemented bbq but +1 for the additional option

Answer (score -1):

Two ideas:

1) onbeforeunload. Ask the user if they want to really go back.

2) Sandwidch a redirect page. Login -> redirect -> your page. A single back click would take the user to your redirect page.

The second is kind of a pain in the neck for people who know what they're doing though. I think the Back button (and all standard navigational elements) should be messed with as little as possible.

I would go with onbeforeunload:

```
function sure()
{
  event.returnValue = "sure?";
} 

... 

<BODY onbeforeunload="sure()">
```

Comment: much better to use one of the history or state management plugins to make the page work towards user expectations rather than redirect them